# merge two table record in one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a quetion regarding merge two data table. i have two table Table1 and Table2, In Table 1 there are two column and 10 row and in Table2 there are 5 row and one column. Now i able to find the solution for that how i merge and calulate desired result

```
Table1

SNO - Name  -  Amount 
1   -   A   -   10
2   -   B   -   20
3   -   C   -   30
4   -   D   -   40
5   -   E   -   50
6   -   F   -   60
7   -   G   -   70
8   -   H   -   80
9   -   I   -   90
10  -   J   -   100

Table2

Rate(%)  
  20   
  30   
  50   
  60   
  10 
Now I want result like this

New_Amount Calculation -> (Amount*Rate)/100)

   SNO  - Name  -  Amount -  New_Amount 
    1   -   A   -   10    -    2
    2   -   B   -   20    -    6
    3   -   C   -   30    -    15
    4   -   D   -   40    -    24
    5   -   E   -   50    -    20
    6   -   F   -   60    -    12
    7   -   G   -   70    -    21
    8   -   H   -   80    -    24
    9   -   I   -   90    -    54
    10  -   J   -   100    -   10
```

Here [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51519)

```
NOte: There no relation between both table
```

Comment: how would you like to match the rows if there is no key in table 2? What is the ordering on table 2?  SQL has no inherent ordering.

Comment: @DanielE. It is just a example you can put no key on table but remmeber There no relation between both table..

Comment: then what logic do you want to apply? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Is there any SNO column in your table as it is not shown in your fiddle? I agree with Daniel that SQL has no inherent ordering.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see how you're getting a possible `Rate` for SNOs 6 -> 10, but it looks like a simple join would suffice here:

```
select
    t1.SNO,
    t1.Name,
    t1.Amount,
    New_Amount = (t1.Amount * t2.Rate) / 100
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2
on t1.SNO = t2.SNO;
```

Comment: The OP didn't say a lot about the surrounding situation, so assumptions were made.

Comment: Ok, well you just edited out the implicit relationship between the two tables.  In which case, what would be the business logic to determine which rate a particular SNO gets applied to it?